# uniform инициализация

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор

Есть функция, которая принимает параметр `LARGE_INTEGER`

```cpp
void test(LARGE_INTEGER arg);
```

Вопрос: могу ли я ее вызвать таким образом

```cpp
void test(LARGE_INTEGER{0});
```

или я обязательно должен объявлять отдельную переменную

```cpp
LARGE_INTEGER prm;
prm.QuadPart = 0;
void test(prm);
```

Структура `LARGE_INTEGER` объявлена в `winnt.h` следующим образом

```c
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

**Update**

Немного расширю вопрос. Сейчас почитал, что для инициализации нулем достаточно написать `LARGE_INTEGER{}`. А если не нулем? `LARGE_INTEGER{7}` корректно будет?

Comment: можно, разрешаем.

Comment: @KoVadim как оно будет работать? Смущает отсутствие конструктора `LARGE_INTEGER(long long)`

Comment: Так как это структура, то как и любая структура   -> см. коммент KoVadim.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov показывайте устройство LARGE_INTEGER. Но в любом случае всегда можно дописать подходящий конструктор, который будет принимать именно нужный Вам параметр и правильно инициализировать объект

Comment: Конструктор  тут и не нужен для списка инициализации

Comment: @KoVadim показал

Comment: union... интересно. Да, можно и другим числом инициализировать. Но в этом коде очень легко поймать UB. Так что я был бы крайне осторожным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется инициализировать произвольным числом, то следует обращать внимание на то, что инициализируется. При вызове `LARGE_INTEGER{7}` число будет использовано для инициализации `LowPart`, и если значение большое - оно будет будет требовать подрезания. Так что придется инициализировать по частям `LARGE_INTEGER{0xFF'FF'FF'FF, 0x00'00'00'0F};`. Чтобы сразу инициализировать `QuadPart` необходимо использовать синтаксис designated initializers, доступный в С++20: `LARGE_INTEGER f{.QuadPart{0x00'00'00'0F'FF'FF'FF'FF}};`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что при инициализации `LARGE_INTEGER{7}` также будет инициализирована  `HighPart` нулём или нет?

Comment: и надо понимать, что это будет инициализироваться от DUMMYSTRUCTNAME

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Да.